# How to restart the networking service?

Tags: networking, services

I tried to use

```
sudo service networking restart
```

and

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network restart
```

but they both crash the window manager and I can no longer use my keyboard for input into X.

when I use the `/etc/init.d/` method it complains saying that I should use the service utility

```
e.g. service networking restart
```

but it crashes just the same.

Is there a GUI method of restarting networking?

Comment: Note that you might reanimate your keyboard, if you unplug and replug it - and it is hot pluggable, i.e. USB.

Comment: I also faced similar issue on Gnome 3 on Ubuntu 13.03. Screen disorted as top bar gone. Short keys not worked. As no menu/Activies shown I get no way to operate the system. Luckily console was opened already. So reboot command can  be typed.

Comment: if you are looking for GUI method just open dash, type "Network" and select that. now press "On/Off" button to turn off and again click to on. your networking is restarted now.

Answer (score 338):

### For Desktops

Try

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Or on recent Ubuntu versions:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

instead.

Ubuntu uses network-manager instead of the traditional Linux networking model. so you should restart the `network-manager` service instead of the `network` service. Or [use ifup/down](https://askubuntu.com/a/376586/235).

### For Servers

Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/376586/6005).

Comment: hmm, strange that restarting just networking breaks the system. Does it happen to you too or is it just me?

Comment: @waspinator - it happens to me too. (FYI.)

Comment: Autocomplete give `networking`, however , the right cmd is `network-manager`

Comment: I wish I had tried Jorge's answer first.

Comment: As of 18.04.2 the answer is: `systemctl restart systemd-networkd`

Comment: On my Desktop system this answer gave me `Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.` I found the answer from @dagrha seems to work.

Comment: As of 2024.01 the answer for Ubuntu is `systemctl restart NetworkManager`.

Answer (score 123):

### For Servers

Restarting networking on a desktop machine will cause dbus and a bunch of service to stop and never be started again, usually leading to the whole system being unusable.

As Ubuntu does event based network bring up, there quite simply isn't a way to undo it all and redo it all, so a restart just isn't plain possible. The recommended way instead is to use ifdown and ifup on the interfaces you actually want to reconfigure:

```
sudo ifdown --exclude=lo -a && sudo ifup --exclude=lo -a
```

Comment: I'm getting `ifup: failed to open lockfile /run/network/.ifstate.lock: Permission denied` even on `--force`

Comment: @Jorge Castro: is this behavior going to be fixed, or is it broken by design?

Comment: @waspinator the bug is marked fixed as of march of this year: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus/+bug/1072518

Comment: what's the purpose of `exclude=lo` here?

Comment: @JeffAtwood Loopback is used for X, dbus etc. Disabling it causes... issues.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu Server 16.04.1.  Ubuntu Server doesn't appear to include Network Manager, so http://askubuntu.com/a/230751/13756 doesn't work.

Comment: The `ifdown --exclude=lo -a && ifup --exclude=lo -a` command did not work for Ubuntu Server 14.04. The `ifconfig eth0 down && ifconfig eth0 up` command worked (https://askubuntu.com/a/230804/134723).

Comment: Thus save my life, since I run `/etc/init.d/iptables restart` on my VPS, which turns the host has no ip address even after reboot. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 45):

You could try

```
ifconfig eth0 down && ifconfig eth0 up
```

(or whatever your network interface is called) to restart the network.

Comment: ... as far as I know, this doesn't update the interface's config according to /etc/network/interfaces ... which you might want

Comment: When using sudo: sudo ifconfig eth0 down && sudo ifconfig eth0 up. Otherwise if you are connected over ssh, you will have to reboot machine.

Comment: after trying ifup/ifdown and the reg service networking call, this finally worked for me

Comment: I think it's better than the accepted answer because `ifup` doesn't handle bonded interfaces correctly, while `ifconfig` does

Answer (score 22):

ubuntu CLI: to restart the network service either

`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

or

```
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
```

Comment: This used to work for older kernels. Now it seems that do not work indeed. Prefered ifconfig eth0 down & ifconfig eth0 up

Comment: Beware not to use this command when connecting on remote machine.

Answer (score 18):

These days the most direct way to restart network services is to use *systemd* controls, namely the commandline systemd control utility `systemctl`. This command will restart the NetworkManager:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

More information can be found [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#).

Comment: Try "systemctl restart networking.service" on server 16.04.

Comment: Don't need the ".service" part at the end.

Answer (score 18):

For ubuntu server 18.04, this works :

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Comment: To new LTS 20.04 the comand above work, thanks!

Comment: I confirm! This works on 20.04! Thanks!

Comment: Why oh why do they change the name every year. Sigh. That works on 20.04.

Answer (score 9):

`service network-manager restart` doesn't work:

```
stop: Unknown job network-manager
start: Unknown job network-manager
```

The only thing that works is:

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

nor:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Doesn't work on Ubuntu server 14.04

only:

```
sudo ifdown eth0:0
sudo ifup eth0:0
```

Works. Change **eth0:0** to your interface.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the indicator (top menu bar)  to disable and then enable networking.

Answer (score 6):

I've got the same issue. Its a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus/+bug/1102507

Using `service network-manager restart` works through

Comment: This is solution which works always on 16.04. In my experience Ubuntu 16.04 have issues to restart Wi-Fi after returning from hibernation.

Answer (score 5):

I do not really think there's GUI method - by default at least.

I'm also not sure what do You mean by 'restarting networking service', but I feel that the following could help.

## Before Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo killall NetworkManager
```

It kills NetworkManger which automatically restarts after this.
It doesn't break the system.

## Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo killall NetworkManager && sudo NetworkManager
```

Based on my personal experience, it seems that in Ubuntu 16.04 NetworkManager does not always restart by itself and it's better to start it manually.

Comment: How is this better than `sudo service network-manager restart` and why?

Comment: @Underverse, I believe that `sudo service network-manager restart` just didn't work for me when posting this answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you can restart the network using the applet of NetworkManager, you do not need to restart NetworkManager itself (at least, most of the time).

In that case to restart all the connections, use this code from a shell or in a script:

```
nmcli nm enable false
sleep 5
nmcli nm enable true
```

Details can be found in the [NetworkManagar command-line interface manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nmcli.1.html).

Notice that these commands acts as the applet, so *they do not need any additional privilege* (no `sudo` or whatever).

Answer (score 4):

In ubuntu 14.04 they have a new "feature" that makes it impossible to restart.
Force the interface down and up works.

```
  sudo ip link set eth0 down
  sudo ip link set eth0 up
```

Comment: This does not restart the network services, that is, no retry for DHCP addresses etc.

Answer (score 2):

if ubuntu 14.04 Desktop or Server, you can restart you network by:

```
sudo -i
( ifdown $(ifquery --list -X lo|xargs echo) && ifup $(ifquery --list -X lo|xargs echo) )&
```

Comment: I get a `ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.`

Answer (score 2):

I am able to restart the network service on ubuntu with command.

```
 sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Answer (score 1):

rmano's answer is brilliant. Solves so many issues.

Remark to improve: 
In U15 I experience a different syntax for nmcli:

For analysis do:

```
nmcli networking connectivity
```

To stop service do:

```
nmcli networking off
```

and to restart do:

```
nmcli networking on
```

No sudo required. Thanks rmano!

Answer (score 1):

This uses Ubuntu's network-manager to disable, then enable eth0:

```
nmcli nm enable false eth0 && nmcli nm enable true eth0
```

If your connection has a different name, use it. You can learn your connections name by using the command:

```
nmcli c status
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach for the server (as of Ubuntu 18.04):

1. Install ifupdown2 package :
   `apt install ifupdown2`
2. Use `service networking restart` command