# No network connection on an HP ProBook 4530s

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet

I own a HP probook 4530s.

I installed ubuntu 12.04 along side my windows 7 professional OS.  While in window 7 everything works properly in terms of wire and wireless connection.

On Ubuntu 12.04 my wired connection doesn't work at all and wireless connection works only when I check off enable wireless then recheck enable wireless.

When I recheck enable wireless, the wireless connection only works for about 30 seconds then it goes offline again.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu usually allows you to easily connect to a wireless network by just clicking the name of the network you'd like to use, but most wifi cards need a proprietary driver to work. So go to the "System Settings" > "Additional Drivers" to see if you need to install a proprietary driver for your wifi card.

So if new drivers need to be installed do so by using a wired connection or a mobile broadband.

Can you give the output when you run 
    `ifconfig`
and
    `sudo lshw -C network` 
on your terminal

and as far as wired connection is concerned

Login as root

type :
    `gedit /etc/network/interfaces`
 in the terminal window.

add the following lines to the end of the file
    `auto eth0`

```
`iface eth0 inet dhcp`
```

save and quit.

now restart the network.
    - [How to restart the networking service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230698/how-to-restart-the-networking-service)