# static ip no internet

Tags: ip

So I followed these steps to get static ip and lost connection

```
sudo -s
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

changed

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

to same as above with

```
auto eth-d
iface eth0 inet static
address etc
```

then reset networking

Comment: Could you be more clear on what you are trying to achieve ? Do you have `network-manager` installed ? AFAIK if you have `network-manager` installed wired connection is controlled by `network-manager` and you need to setup static ip through `network-manager` interface

Comment: The formatting is hard to read. `eth0` in the first and `eth-d` in the second example? What's that meant to be? How did you "reset" networking?

Answer (score 3):

Your file is misconfigured, try something like this:

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(enter your ip here)
        netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(enter gateway ip here,usually the address of the router)
        DNS xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Then:

- [How to restart the networking service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230698/how-to-restart-the-networking-service)