# How to restart networking? eth0 RJ45 does not connect after sleep mode in Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, xubuntu, network-manager

After I sleep down my notebook (Xubuntu 12.04) and wake up, my network setting goes often corrupted and does not work. Only solution seems to be restart.

Connecting and disconnecting in network manager or `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` and later `up` does not help.

Sometimes the RJ45 connector is blinking, sometimes not even that. Occasionally other network cards (Wifi) gets jammed similarly, but I do not use them so often and I do not know if this is the same problem.

I'm running a virtualbox Windows 7 bridged to both network interfaces, do not know if there is some glue to that problem.

**Is there a way how to completely init the network module in case this happen?**

**Edit**: Using the responses bellow I have discovered, that nothing from `sudo service networking restart` or `/etc/init.d/networking restart` helped to bring the network card alive, once it gets "dead". Sometimes, the card is not even blinking like it would be disabled. Sometimes card is blinking, but no response, no IP address is assigned. Only solution is to switch notebook off and on again. Could it be a hardware problem? I have little comparison with dual-booted Windows, but it happens so rarely, that I had no opportunity to observe it on different OS.

Comment: This sounds like  bug #1234469: (Network does not come up after resuming from suspend). Look at the answers to http://askubuntu.com/questions/361991/suspend-problems-in-13-10 for workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Recommended method:

The best way to restart networking is to do this:

- [How to restart the networking service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230698/how-to-restart-the-networking-service)

though this is not a permanent solution to your problem.

### Alternate(deprecated) method:

This one, though deprecated, is to do a `/etc/init.d/networking restart`. This is relatively verbose and explains what is going wrong(if there is anything going wrong).

Comment: will try when it happen again and let you know if this works. Permanent solution is not absolutely necessary, linux is for geeks.

Comment: tried and no result with both methods. :c( Edited a question accordingly.