# How to change ip address in ubuntu desktop through command line

Tags: command-line, networking, network-manager

In Ubuntu desktop 13.04 changing `/etc/network/interfaces` file don't change ip address or convert DHCP to static network interface configuration. after changing the file I tried

```
sudo service networking restart
```

----------EDIT----------

I have connected to system with ssh.

Comment: How are you changing the IP when editing the` /etc/network/interfaces` file?

Comment: @Mitch [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1806929)

Comment: You mean to say you edited that file but it doesn't have any effect? It doesn't change the IP address?

Comment: @Alaa i did `sudo service networking restart`

Answer (score 8):

By default, Ubuntu (or Network Manager to be specific) ignores the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. To make the changes you made take effect, execute the following commands:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0
```

Assuming that `wlan0` is the interface you are editing. Once you do that, `wlan0` will come up with the settings you have under its stanza in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

---

**Edit:** since you're connected through SSH. You can try the following:

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and change `ifdown managed` to `false`:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Then, try:

- [How to restart the networking service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230698/how-to-restart-the-networking-service)

Comment: if i use ifdown i will loose connection to the system. If it dont work there is no way to connect again.

Comment: i can try restarting the system but if static ip is not set i cant know its dynamic new ip

Comment: @neckTwi try my updated answer. Also, are you sure it's going to have a different IP? Usually, there's a lease period where, even if you restart the machine, it'll still get the same IP until the pre-defined lease period expires. But that depends of course, I'm just saying what's on my mind.

Comment: what does `[ifupdown] managed=false` mean?

Comment: If it is set to true, NetworkManager "manages" the interfaces mentioned in `/etc/network/interfaces`. If it's set to false, NetworkManager does not manage the interfaces mentioned there.

Comment: @neckTwi so did it work? You should also try `sudo service network-manager restart`.

Comment: I want NetworkManager to manage the interfaces. The system is used as regular desktop. I risked restarting the system and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo -i
gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

This is done with the help of [guntbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/117103/guntbert)

Once done save and exit

add this line
DHCP mode

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Static mode

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Once done save the file, and:

```
sudo service resolvconf restart
```

- [How to restart the networking service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230698/how-to-restart-the-networking-service)

Comment: These aren't permanent changes. They'll be overridden when the computer restarts.

Comment: that dont survive system restart

Comment: Do you have a static or dynamic IP?

Comment: @guntbert Is this better?  Thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't work (or no longer works). Ubuntu doesn't seem to care about `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 4):

You can change your ip address by using the following script:

Open terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> and type the following command:

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

OR

```
gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Find eth0 section and setup IP address as follows:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.2.0
broadcast 192.168.2.255
```

Save and close the file. Once done, restart network:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Verify new IP address by using the following command :

```
$ ifconfig eth0
$ ifconfig
```

Comment: This is just a vehicle for your own websites; please disclose your affiliation to `ip-details.com` and `Whoisxy.com`, or *don't link to these sites from all your posts*. See the [help/behavior].

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this answer to give another dimension to the question and existing answers, not as a direct answer to the original question. Your IP will be lost at reboot. However, I think it's worth you understanding these commands, `iproute2` package is the currently method of on-the-fly interface management via the CLI. Lots of people are still writing scripts using `ifconfig` for example.

I think it's worth noting the use of the `iproute2` packages;

Show current IPs on all interface (`ip addr`)

```
n2:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:6d:0a:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:ea:3a:ad:2e:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.22.0.221/24 brd 172.22.0.255 scope global wlan0
    inet6 fe80::76ea:3aff:fead:2e00/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Add an IP address to my wireless interface (`ip addr add`)

```
n2:~$ sudo ip a a 10.0.0.56/24 dev wlan0
[sudo] password for bensley:
```

Show my IP addresses again, note the additional IP on wlan0 (`ip addr`)

```
n2:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:6d:0a:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:ea:3a:ad:2e:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.22.0.221/24 brd 172.22.0.255 scope global wlan0
    inet 10.0.0.56/24 scope global wlan0
    inet6 fe80::76ea:3aff:fead:2e00/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Show the link state of my interfaces (`ip link`)

```
n2:~$ ip l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:6d:0a:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:ea:3a:ad:2e:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Delete this 2nd IP address from my wireless interface (`ip addr delete`)

```
n2:~$ sudo ip a del 10.0.0.56/24 dev wlan0
```

Show IP addresses just for wlan0 to check (`ip addr show wlan0`)

```
n2:~$ ip a s wlan0
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:ea:3a:ad:2e:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.22.0.221/24 brd 172.22.0.255 scope global wlan0
    inet6 fe80::76ea:3aff:fead:2e00/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The same commands could have been used to remove my current IP, 172.22.0.221 then add another, but I would have lost connectivity, which I can't right now. Below are those commands though, after which I would also need to add a new default route route;

```
n2:~$ ip r s
default via 172.22.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0  scope link  metric 1000 
172.22.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.22.0.221  metric 2 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1

ip a del 172.22.0.221/24 dev wlan0

ip a a 172.22.0.10/24 dev wlan

ip r a default via 172.22.0.1

# Re-add the same default route ^ via the same default gateway
```

Answer (score 0):

From t[he detailed instructions on this site](http://www.sudo-juice.com/how-to-set-a-static-ip-in-ubuntu-the-proper-way/):

1. disable the graphical management of your network connection in
   /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
2. Gather the information for the static IP (interface, IP to be used, 
   default gateway, subnet,DNS)
3. Modify /etc/network/interfaces to include the information
   above.
4. Restart networking and network-manager services

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do it.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 <type_IP_you want>
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```