# Saved IPv4 static config file location, on Ubuntu Desktop 17.10?

Tags: command-line, networking, 17.10, files, dhcp

I've search for a many time the location of this file.

When I make changes in Wired Connection on Ubuntu Desktop (for example on Manual/Static IP) where Ubuntu saved changes?

I tried on `/etc/netplan`, `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/NetworkManager` but those are not the files with the content I am searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the static IP in Network Manager, which I recommend if it is running and installed on your system, the information will be found in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired\ connection\ 1`.

A redacted sample might look something like:

```
[ipv4]
address1=192.168.0.120/24,192.168.0.1
dns=8.8.8.8;8.8.4.4;
dns-search=
ignore-auto-dns=true
may-fail=false
method=manual

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns=2001:4860:4860::8888;2001:4860:4860::8844;
dns-search=
ignore-auto-dns=true
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto
```

Comment: In case somebody needs to apply the newly edited ip address, you can type: sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

Answer (score 0):

You may find it here

```
/sys/class/net
```

PS: I haven't checked that. Got this information from [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic)

You can also try editing this file

```
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Also try checking this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/335354/701605)