# Cannot find device "eth0". Failed to bring up eth0

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I'm trying to configure a ubuntu server network.

[Edit]
My ifconfig:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>
loop txqueuelen 1000 (Loopback Local)
RX packets 352 bytes 26160 (26.1KB)
RX erors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 352 bytes 26160 (26.1KB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

I edited the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and here is how it is:

```
auto lo
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.15.141
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.15.1
```

I'm trying to restart the server and I'm using:

```
sudo ifdown --exclude=lo -a && sudo ifup --exclude=lo -a
```

This command is an answer from this link: [How to restart the networking service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230698/how-to-restart-the-networking-service/376586#376586)

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot find device "eth0"
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

I'm pretty lay in configuring a server, so I have no idea what's going on.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `ifconfig` terminal command.

Comment: The Ethernet port might be named something like `enp3s0` or something like that.   Try the output of `ifconfig -a` so it shows all ports detected on the system.

Comment: So, I don't know how to copy and paste and I have to write everything down.
I got ens160: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu...

is it helpful?

Comment: Ens160 is the name of the Ethernet.  Change the settings from eth0 to match that name instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you amend your `/etc/network/interfaces` file to read:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
address 192.168.15.141
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.15.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.15.1 8.8.8.8
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown ens160 && sudo ifup -v ens160
```

Did you connect?

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```