# Ubuntu server has no internet connection after upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, upgrade, ssh

I'm a bit new to linux and ubuntu specially command line stuff.
So I currently have a VPS which was running on a 14.04 ubuntu LTS, and as I needed a 16.04 version, I searched and found the way to upgrade it. I SSHed into the server and started upgrading, everything went well and it asked for a restart and I let it. After that I'm not able to to ssh into it. I had a KVM thingy with a VNC to connect and see what is going on. I don't know if an ubuntu server should boot on default (log in a user) or not, but it wasn't booting and there was a message :

`/dev/vda1: clean, xxxx/xxxx files, xxxx/xxxx blocks`

so I went to manually login using ctrl + alt + f2 and it is upgraded to 16.04 and the SSH service is running with no problem, but I noticed I couldn't do `apt-get update` or anything similar because I have no internet connection and after 24 hours searching I've come here asking for help.

I don't if it may help but these are the results of the commands I've ran

`sudo lshw -C network`
gives:
[lshw -C network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EtWE.png)

and `systemctl status networking.service` gives :
[systemctl status networking.service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLMVN.png)

Comment: Manually try `sudo ifup -a --read-environment` and see if you get any more error messages.

Comment: @Jos Thanks for the time, it gives me `Cannot find device "eth0", Failed to bring up "eth0"`

Comment: Ah. Your `/etc/network/interfaces` probably still refers to `eth0`, whereas as of 16.04, the interface has been given a new name. See this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/953071/cannot-find-device-eth0-failed-to-bring-up-eth0

Comment: In fact, replace `eth0` by `vethb436ed8` in `/etc/network/interfaces` and do `systemctl restart networking`.

Comment: @Jos Brilliant, Thanks. if You post it as answer I'll mark it as solution. thanks dude.

Comment: @Jos oh btw I replaced it with ens3 because after I entered `ifconfig -a` I saw ens3 and used that? It is working now should I use the other or if it is working I shouldn't touch it? :))

Comment: Use whatever works. I found the `vethb436ed8` a bit strange anyway (suggests a virtual interface). `ens3` sounds more familiar.