# Problem to restart network

Tags: networking, network-manager

When I type:

`systemctl restart networking.service`

this error message show:

`failed to restart networking.service: Unit networking.service not found`

I use ubuntu server 20.04 LTS

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/376586/1222991) from a few years back should do what you need 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restart the networking service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230698/how-to-restart-the-networking-service)

Answer (score 1):

The correct command is

```
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

The service is called `systemd-networkd`, not `networking`.

Comment: Please check again: Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.

Comment: @chili555 Fixed, this should work now